# Return Eloquent rows with columns based on privacy

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `users` table with the following Schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username', 50);
        $table->text('first_name');
        $table->text('last_name');
        $table->text('phone1');
        $table->boolean('is_private_phone1');
        $table->text('phone2');
        $table->boolean('is_private_phone2');
        $table->text('email');
        $table->boolean('is_private_email');
        $table->string('headshot', 32);
        $table->string('password', 64);
        $table->string('remember_token', 100);
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I want to get the list of users. But I don't want to get the `phone1`, `phone2`, and `email` of those who have set the privacy to private to be returned (i.e. if you do have a privacy, then only your name and headshot is returned. If you don't then your phone and email are already returned).

Is there a way to do this in Eloquent? All I can think of is to get all the rows, and manually loop through them and remove the columns after.

Comment: You could override the `toArray` method and hide the properties in there. Tell me if you're interested in such a solution and I'll write up an answer

Comment: @lukasgeiter, thanks for the response. Actually I think I am going to use the Accessor method, since it seems to provide the best solution. I am going to post a reply. If you think your answer is better, then by all means please post it

Comment: Well it depends on your use case. Do you need the properties to be private already when working with the model or only when returning the response (as json for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also add a `scope` method like this:

```
public function scopeWithPrivacy($query)
{
    if($this->isPrivate('email')) {
        return $query->select(['name', 'headshot']);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Call the method like:

```
$user = User::withPrivacy()->find(1);
```

So, when you call the `withPrivacy()` method then the privacy check will be done and fields will be returned accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the accessors. I added the following functions to the `User` model:

```
public function getEmailAttribute($value)
{
    if ( ! $this->isPrivate('email')) return $value;

    return null;
}

public function getPhone1Attribute($value)
{
    if ( ! $this->isPrivate('phone1')) return $value;

    return null;
}

public function getPhone2Attribute($value)
{
    if ( ! $this->isPrivate('phone2')) return $value;

    return null;
}

private function isPrivate($field)
{
    $field = 'is_private_' . $field;

    return $this->attributes[$field] == 1;
}
```